# Python smtplib Blank Message

Tags: python, smtplib

Having an issue with smtplib sending a blank body, even though the value will print to console just fine.

Parent method:

```
    recipient = 'dummied@dummied.com'
    text = 'Subject: Employee Departure Notification.\n%s has left Redcated.  Their termination is effective %s.' % (employee_name, text)
    print('SMTP text: ', text)
    message = smtpObj.sendmail(config['Email']['username'], recipient, text)
```

This works fine with this portion of code:

```
if 
    i['request_variables'][4]['value'] == 'Immediately':                                                                   
    text = 'their termination is effective immediately'
```

BUT does not work with the following although it prints the correct logic to console (blank body but email sends otherwise)

```
last_day_long = datetime.strptime(last_day, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(hours=17)
last_day = str(last_day_long)
text = 'their termination is effective %s at 5:00pm' % last_day
print('Last day value before email: ', last_day)
```

Please ignore my terrible code and formatting, appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue - Needed to line break twice instead of once from Subject --> Header --> Body to get the last snippet to work. No idea why it worked in the second block but I'll take it.